# Calculate the maximum of repetitive elements in certain portions of a matrix

Tags: matlab, unique

I have a 2000x2 matrix, and **"for each 10x2 segment of this matrix"**, I need to calculate the maximum of corresponding values (second column) of repetitive values (first column) in the matrix. Like if the 3rd 10x2 segment of the matrix is this:

```
...
[2 20;
2 30;
2 40;
7 100;
7 110;
7 120;
7 130;
7 140;
15 240;
15 260]
 ...
```

I want to get this:

```
...
[2 40;
7 140;
15 260]
 ...
```

And so on. I have written the following but it gives me the maximum of repetitive elements through the "whole matrix":

```
[uv,~,idx] = unique(A(:,1));
B = [uv accumarray(idx,A(:,2),[],@max)];
```

But again, I need to do this **"for each separate 10x2 segments of the matrix"**, and then store the results in a *'whatever x 2'* sized matrix! Does anyone have any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: I'd start by reshaping the matrix into a `10 x N x 2` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `A(:,2)` as the argument to accumarray you can use indices of values and use them to extract elements in the function handle.

```
A = randi(5,50,2);
val = (1:size(A,1)).';
B = accumarray( ...
    [A(:,1) ceil(val/10)], val, [], ...
    @(x){[ A(x(1), 1) max(A(x, 2)) ]} ...
);
result = vertcat(B{:});
```